# D'ou vient l'expression « Cul-de-Sac » ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

L'expression un Cul-de-sac est habituellement un rue sans issue.

Mais je vois mal comment un cul ou un sac a rapport au fait qu'une rue se termine sans amener à une autre route.

Alors d'ou vient l'expression Cul-de-Sac?

Comment: http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/cul-de-sac Cul: fonds ou partie inférieure de quelque chose

Comment: Sa ne donne pas grand réponses.

Comment: une rue sans issue ressemble au fond d'un sac.....

Comment: 1307 cul-de-çac « rue sans issue, impasse » (Mem. Soc. Hist. Paris, XVIII, 177 ds Gdf. Compl. Il me semble que 1307, ça fait un bail.

Answer (score 2):

Au *Trésor de la langue française*, [*cul*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/cul) :

> III {Par analogie des emplois I & II}
>   A. {Par analogie de position} Partie inférieure ou postérieure d’une chose

De nombreux composés et expressions courantes en français utilisent cette acception non vulgaire :

- Cul-de-basse-fosse → cachot souterrain, au fond d’une basse-fosse *(la basse-fosse étant elle-même un cachot très profond)*
- Cul-de-bouteille → un vert très foncé rappelant la couleur du verre épais du fond d’une bouteille
- Cul-de-lampe → support en encorbellement dont la forme rappelle le dessous d’une lampe d’église
- Cul de marmite → le fond d’une marmite
- Faire cul-sec → boire un verre d’un trait, laissant sec le fond du verre

---

Un sac ne débouchant sur rien lorsqu’on l’explore *(dans sa version la plus simple et la plus commune, il n’y a qu’un seul point d’accès vers l’intérieur du sac)*, on entend par métaphore **cul-de-sac** comme une voie sans issue. On peut l’utiliser en effet pour une voie carossable qui se termine sans nouvelle intersection, et donc sans autre possibilité de rejoindre le réseau routier qu’en revenant sur ses pas.

Il existe cependant d’autres utilisations possibles :

- En demeurant sur les chemins, on pourrait dire de la route qui mène de Rae-Edzo à Yellowknife, dans le Grand-Nord canadien, est un **cul-de-sac**, bien qu’elle débouche sur une ville, Yellowknife, qui possède de nombreuses rues, et que quelqu’un pourrait bien faire une grande boucle dans la ville sans devoir revenir sur son chemin. Par contre, si l’on désire sortir avec son véhicule routier de la ville pour se rendre ailleurs sur le continent, et à l’exception de deux routes locales ne menant pas très loin de la ville, on doit obligatoirement refaire ce trajet d’une centaine de kilomètres qui nous ramènera vers Edzo.[image]
- On rencontrera aussi parfois un **cul-de-sac** évolutif en biologie pour désigner une stratégie de survie vouée à l’échec :

  > Les populations qui, aujourd’hui, se reproduisent de cette façon sont relativement récentes. « L’autopollinisation est un **cul-de-sac** évolutif », indique le chercheur. <sub>*(Québec Sciences, mai 1996)*</sub>
- *Et en vrac :*
  La conversation arrive dans un **cul-de-sac**.
  Les négotiations se sont dirigées vers un **cul-de-sac**.
  Les recherches n’ont finalement pas abouti : elles se sont retrouvées dans un **cul-de-sac**.

Comment: Donc, en gros; cul comme le fond de quelque chose et un sac n'a qu'une seule issue, alors le fond n'a pas d'issue, alors cul-de-sac

Comment: @Fredy31 Comme vous dites, oui...